# Partial vs lambda in Python turtle/tkinter events

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, turtle-graphics

In Python **turtle**, if I want to pass an event handler arguments that differ from what the event system specifies, I can use a `lambda` to bridge the difference:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial

def change_color(color, x=None, y=None):
    screen.bgcolor(color)

screen = Screen()

screen.onclick(lambda x, y: change_color('blue'))

screen.mainloop()
```

Or I can use the `partial` function imported from **functools** to replace the `lambda` with:

```
screen.onclick(partial(change_color, 'blue'))
```

And that works *fine*.  Returning to our original program, we can replace our `onclick()` event with an `ontimer()` event, updating our `lambda`, and everything works *fine*:

```
screen.ontimer(lambda: change_color('blue'), 1000)
```

But, when we replace this `lambda` with a `partial`:

```
screen.ontimer(partial(change_color, 'blue'), 1000)
```

It *fails* immediately (not when the timer would have fired) with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    screen.ontimer(partial(change_color, 'blue'), 1000)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1459, in ontimer
    self._ontimer(fun, t)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 718, in _ontimer
    self.cv.after(t, fun)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 755, in after
    callit.__name__ = func.__name__
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'
>
```

Since **turtle** sits atop **tkinter**, and **tkinter** is implicated in the stack trace, we can go down a level:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def change_color(color):
    root.configure(bg=color)

root = tk.Tk()

root.after(1000, change_color, 'blue')

root.mainloop()
```

Which works *fine*.  We can also do:

```
root.after(1000, lambda: change_color('blue'))
```

Which works *fine*.  But when we do:

```
root.after(1000, partial(change_color, 'blue'))
```

it again immediately *fails* with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    root.after(1000, partial(change_color, 'blue'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 755, in after
    callit.__name__ = func.__name__
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'
>
```

The **functools** documentation for `partial` states its return value will behave like a *function* but clearly it's different, if not lacking, somehow.  Why is that?  And why does **tkinter/turtle** accept `partial` functions as *click* event handers, but not as *timer* event handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that?

It's designed this way.
By default, `partial` [stores](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial.func) the packed function without attributes, however they are still available:

```
partial_func = partial(change_color, 'blue')
print(partial_func.func.__name__)
```

You should use [`update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) function (or [a decorator counterpart](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)) to explicitly set correct options:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial, update_wrapper

def change_color(color, x=None, y=None):
    screen.bgcolor(color)

def partial_change_color(color):
    partial_f = partial(change_color, color)
    update_wrapper(partial_f, change_color)

    return partial_f

screen = Screen()

screen.ontimer(partial_change_color('blue'), 1000)

screen.mainloop()
```

> And why does tkinter/turtle accept partial functions as click event handers, but not as timer event handlers?

Again, it's designed this way.
Because binding and scheduling algorithms are slightly different in the tkinter wrapper, which [can be observed if you track down your error](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138ccbb02216ca086047c3139857fb44f3dab1f9/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L792).

`tkinter` creates additional wrapper `callit`, which handles unscheduling of a target function using `__name__` (hence, `AttributeError`), while the binding [does not have such an algorithm for implicit unbinding](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/138ccbb02216ca086047c3139857fb44f3dab1f9/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1328).

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-python/issues/293), it looks like `functools.partial` does not copy the `__module__` and `__name__` attributes from the inner function. You can work around it by defining `__name__` manually:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def change_color(color):
    root.configure(bg=color)

root = tk.Tk()

c = partial(change_color, 'blue')
c.__name__ = "c"

root.after(1000, c)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't need a work around -- as I demonstrated `lambda` works where `partial` fails.  Following up on your answer, thank you, I did two things: I upgraded to the latest Python for my system; I searched for older reports of this error.  It doesn't appear to be fixed in current Python, and reports of it go back over a decade.  I guess my first question is now more like, "Why is it still so?".  My second question of why it affects some tkinter event handlers, but not others, remains unanswered.